# React - MP4 - The file was loaded in a wrong encoding - 'UTF-8'

Tags: reactjs, encoding, webstorm

I've accidentally changed video encoding to UTF-8.

What encoding should I select for the `.mp4` files to work?

H.264 / H.265 is unfortunately not between the options.

I have re-downloaded the original files and imported into project/assets again but actually I have changed settings of the way WebStorm reads the `.mp4` files.

NOTE: Unfortunately I can't post images yet of the encoding options I have.

Comment: mp4 files have no "encoding" in that sense, they're not text. You can't accidentally encode video to UTF-8. Give the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) a read-through, and then edit your post to explain what you set out to do, what code you wrote to do that, what the result of that was and how it didn't match your expectation, _and_ what debugging and (re)searching you've already done to try to fix things.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I didn't write any code in order to change the encoding. I actually just received a popup; which i did not read carefully. 

Basically it mentioned something like it the file was not assigned any encodement and suggested to assign UTF-8 encoding to the mp4 file. I was a bit tired so clicked away.. and that's how it happend. I've worked around it now by using imgr links but.. yeah its still an issue i guess

Comment: @Developsom You need to provide screenshots (much better -- a short video) that would show under what circumstances (what you do) you are seeing this message. **Right now** it sounds like you may have associated `.mp4` files with a Plain Text file type or something like that. Because by default the IDE should NOT try to open it as a text...

Comment: @LazyOne https://imgur.com/d1yjncP Alright, ive uploaded a vid of whats going on and the options i have to change the encoding to.

Comment: Thanks. That helps and clarifies all. As suspected -- for whatever reason (most likely a user mistake) your `.mp4` files are treated as Plain Text files (the file icon indicates that). Go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`, locate `Text` entry and check the associated patterns and remove the offending one. In case it's all good there or you are not sure what should be removed -- post a screenshot of that. Maybe it's another file type...